# Intel OpenCL SDK 2 platforms can't be queried in sequence?

Tags: opencl

I have installed the Intel OpenCL runtime for CPU support from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_windows_release) and also installed the SDK from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl) on a Windows system.  Now, everything appears to be in order and the installations completely without a problem.

I now would like to use a script I usually use for querying OpenCL devices which I have in my github [here](https://github.com/cdeterman/intel_opencl/blob/master/clDeviceQuery.cpp).  This compiles without a problem using the following call:

`g++ -o clDeviceQuery -I"C:\Program FIles (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\include" -L"C:\Program FIles (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\lib\x86" clDeviceQuery.cpp -lOpenCL`

However, when I run the resulting clDeviceQuery.exe file it states there are two OpenCL platforms (I didn't do any other OpenCL installs other than the Intel mentioned above).  Furthermore, it crashes when it tries to query the second platform with the simple popup stating 'clDeviceQuery.exe' has stopped working.  I have no idea why this is happening.

To further complicate things, if I alter the script to only query a specific platform (i.e. the `i` iterator in the loop at line 184 to 0 or 1) it works without a problem.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Once I installed the Intel OpenCL runtime for CPU and discovered two platforms. (Or was it devices?). One implemented OpenCL 1.2 and the other an "experimental" OpenCL 2.0. I was able to print the info on both.

Comment: What are line 185 and 189 supposed to be doing? They seem to do the same thing but 185 sends &cBuffer instead of cBuffer. In my own script I cast the char[] to void*.

Comment: @Andreas 185 is meant to just see if the platform information can be gotten at all and 189 is to actually pull the info.  Does the script work for you with char[] cast to void?

Comment: Ok. Yes it works. For my current computer I get both the CPU and GPU platform and print their info. I´m very positive passing &cBuffer is a mistake as it means sending a char**, not char* (or char[]). Try that and see what happens.

Comment: @Andreas okay, can you post in an answer below exactly what you changed?  I am still having problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a char pointer-to-pointer instead of char pointer to clGetPlatformInfo. Change line 185 from:

```
ciErrNum = clGetPlatformInfo (clPlatformIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 1024, &cBuffer, NULL);
```

To:

```
ciErrNum = clGetPlatformInfo (clPlatformIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 1024, cBuffer, NULL);
```

Explicitly casting cBuffer (char[]) to void* is a matter of preference in this case. I for one prefer it.

---

Ok NOW I GOT IT! FOR REAL!

I ran you program through  Visual Studio debugger and the program crashes at the line (257) with:

> free(clPlatformIDs);

...because it is INSIDE the for loop, not outside. Moving the free() outside the loop makes it work like a charm.

Comment: I have done this and it still crashes when it tries to query the second platform.  It appears to be still getting caught on line 185 which I confirmed by putting two printf statements around it.  Are you certain that is all you changed and it works for you?

Comment: @cdeterman Sorry for being unclear. MY script I wrote a few months ago works like a charm. I have not tried your code. Here is my code (expires in a week): http://pastebin.com/40LdR1ir It has a performance test running after printing all info, never mind that... Lots of other crap experimental code in it too. Try run it and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, yes, that seems to be working fine when I take your code.  I am quite perplexed why my code is failing still though.  I will continue to look at it and return back if I figure something out.  Naturally if you have any further insights they are appreciated.

Comment: @cdeterman Try not to free already freed memory ;-) (read edited answer)

Comment: HUZZAH!!! Yes, that did it.  Thank you, I really needed some outside eyes to look at it.  I knew it had to be something simple.